# Blazor PWA not fetching previously cached API response data offline

Tags: blazor, progressive-web-apps, blazor-webassembly

I have a deployed Blazor PWA running via HTTPS, and validating the service worker is working correctly in the browser. I have a simple HTTP GET call to an API getting data, and I can see when online this data is returned, and the 'initiator' in the dev tools network trace is, `service-worker.js:46` This is a simple API call with a basic query string.

When I toggle the site offline, assets appear to cache OK (.html, .js, etc.) but previously fetched data does not get returned in the browser correctly from the service worker.

The API requests are identical as well as the returned data from the working call (1st call) and the offline attempted call (2nd call):

```
https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=90210&units=imperial&appid=e6ffd
https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=90210&units=imperial&appid=e6ffd
```

The Blazor service worker isn't that complex and debugging it shows the data requested, just doesn't match the cache, and therefore returns an error of 'Failed to fetch' because it can't make a fresh call offline.

These are the 2 main lines of code in the service worker for `onFetch` that *should* return the cached data, but don't:

```
const cache = await caches.open(cacheName);
cachedResponse = await cache.match(request);
```

Looking further, `caches` is only hydrated with *assets* (essentially static files listed in `service-worker-assets.js` that can be seen at runtime, *not* api responses) in the `onInstall` method:

```
async function onInstall(event) {
    console.info('Service worker: Install');

    // Fetch and cache all matching items from the assets manifest
    const assetsRequests = self.assetsManifest.assets
        .filter(asset => offlineAssetsInclude.some(pattern => pattern.test(asset.url)))
        .filter(asset => !offlineAssetsExclude.some(pattern => pattern.test(asset.url)))
        .map(asset => new Request(asset.url, { integrity: asset.hash, cache: 'no-cache' }));
    await caches.open(cacheName).then(cache => cache.addAll(assetsRequests));
}
```

Something still seems missing. From what I see this service worker code is anemic out of the box in Blazor and really only intended for assets. I'm wondering if I need to write additional, custom code to handle api responses, but want to make sure I'm not missing anything 1st. I'm still confused because network traffic *does* indicate subsequent calls are initiated by the service worker. However as shown above when offline, the api responses are not cached. Does anyone know why the data is not being matched in cache and returned? Was this just not a feature ever implemented in the Blazor service-worker?